# Performance issue in c while dealing with 12 digit number

Tags: c

currently i am working on a program. program is working perfectly but it has performance issue. the code is below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int calculate(int temp)
{
    int flag = 0,i = 2,tmp = 0;
    for(i = 2;i < temp;i++)
    {
        if(temp % i == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    long int i = 2,j,count = 0,n = 600851475143,flag = 0,prime = 0;
    long int check;
    while(i < n)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            check = calculate(i);
            if(check != 1)
            {
                prime = i;
                printf(" Prime  number is : %ld \n", prime);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf(" Max prime number of %ld is : %ld \n",n,prime);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't able to get the maximum prime number here.
can anyone tell me what should i do it takes too much time what should i do to get output fast?

Comment: You need a more efficient algorithm, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Please state WHAT the code should do, what it does instead and what you might think is wrong also helps.

Comment: `600851475143` is too long for an `int`, `int calculate(int temp)` -> `long calculate(long temp)`, but as pointed by @KlasLinbäck, this is not an efficient algorithm.

Comment: no return value in `calculate` if `temp` it is a prime. Thats UB. So please look out for those nasal demons, they are nasty. Please compile your code with warnings `-Wall`. There are a bunch of issues you should fix

Comment: @KeineLust depending on the platform a long would also be too small I think

Comment: @KamiKaze, yes, I mean if you use `long int` as an initial value use it also as a parameter in the function, I stand corrected.

Comment: depending on your compiler, even `long int` could be too small for a 12 digit number. I would suggest to use `long long int`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are looking for a *maximum* prime, why are you starting at 2? Begin checking at `n` and work backwards
2. `calculate` can run faster since you only need to check for a divisor up to `sqrt(temp)`, if it has a divisor larger than that, it also has a divisor smaller than that.
3. Your loop increments and decrements can be done in hops of 2. So you'd also halve the range of numbers to check.
4. Calling `printf` in the middle of a search loop for when the check fails is just a waste of execution speed. Instead, check for success and break out of the loop.

With these modifications in mind (and your code cleaned from a lot of UB):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int calculate(long int temp)
{
    long int flag = 0,i = 2,tmp = 0;

    if (temp % 2 == 0)
        return 1;

    for(i = 3; i*i <= temp; i+=2)
    {
        if(temp % i == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    long int j, count = 0, n = 600851475143, i = n, flag = 0, prime = 0;
    long int check;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            check = calculate(i);
            if(check)
            {
                prime = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        i-=2;
    }
    printf(" Max prime number of %ld is : %ld \n",n,prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (long)int calculate (long temp) would be better.

Comment: @KamiKaze - Indeed it would. I was too excited to notice :)

Comment: still having issues regarding execution.

Comment: @DhavalMistry - Finding primes is a notoriously difficult problem in computer science. A naive algorithm, even with some optimization tricks, will not give you stellar run times.

Comment: @DhavalMistry - I did some more tweaks. And I'm about done.

Comment: @DhavalMistry This is all with the assumption that `long int` is a 64 bit integer. You should use `long long int` to be sure and portable. But they should only being used when needed as they may slow down the execution time. a `char` or `int` would suffice for check.